# Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin & MAUI Notify Event throwing an error

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to enable the notify event for a Telink Bluetooth Mesh Device. I am using Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.7.2) and created a MAUI App with the Plugin.BLE (Version 3.0.0-beta.5). I can connect to the device and send command successfully but do not get any replies back regarding whether the command was successful. I know it was successful because I can see the device made the requested change.

Here is my code. The `GetNotifyCharacteristic()` returns the correct notify characteristic, but throws and error when trying to enable the notification

```cs
private async Task EnableNotifications()
{
    try
    {
        //  Guid ="00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1911" Notify Characteristic
        NotifyCharacteristic = await GetNotifyCharacteristic();
        NotifyCharacteristic.WriteType = CharacteristicWriteType.Default;

        if (NotifyCharacteristic.CanUpdate)
        {
            NotifyCharacteristic.ValueUpdated -= CharacteristicOnValueUpdated;
            NotifyCharacteristic.ValueUpdated += CharacteristicOnValueUpdated;
            await NotifyCharacteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Enable Notify Error : " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void CharacteristicOnValueUpdated(object sender, CharacteristicUpdatedEventArgs characteristicUpdatedEventArgs)
{
    var test = characteristicUpdatedEventArgs.Characteristic.Value;
}
```

This is the error:

> [BluetoothGatt] setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1911 enable: true
>
> [BluetoothGatt] onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=9 device=FF:FF:20:98:3B:C0
>
> [BluetoothGatt] close()
>
> [BluetoothGatt] unregisterApp() - mClientIf=9
>
> ```
> [0:] Enable Notify Error : System.Exception: GattStatus: 133
> at Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Utils.TaskBuilder.<SafeEnqueueAndExecute>d__11`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in D:\a\dotnet-bluetooth-le\dotnet-bluetooth-le\Source\Plugin.BLE\Shared\Utils\TaskBuilder.cs:line 96
> at Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Utils.TaskBuilder.<FromEvent>d__9`3[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.EventHandler`1[[Plugin.BLE.Android.CallbackEventArgs.DescriptorCallbackEventArgs, Plugin.BLE, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.EventHandler, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in D:\a\dotnet-bluetooth-le\dotnet-bluetooth-le\Source\Plugin.BLE\Shared\Utils\TaskBuilder.cs:line 48
> at Plugin.BLE.Android.Characteristic.StartUpdatesNativeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

More Error detail when using Plugin.BLE sample App:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing `NotifyCharacteristic.WriteType = CharacteristicWriteType.Default;`? With GATT, each characteristic usually can be used to either write or read, but not both at the same time, AFAIK. Since you're using that characteristic to listen to changes, you shouldn't set the `WriteType` on it, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have tried all the options, and removing it with the same result. I do write a 1 to the characteristic in order to enable the notify option on the device. That writes successfully.